# name not defined in python module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I see python throwing the below error

> "errorMessage": "name 'get_client' is not defined",

Below is my code

```
get_client()

def get_client():
    # optional fields
    level = 'INFO'
    verify = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call or execute the function before it was defined.

Try to alter the order of the 2 parts:

```
def get_client():
    # optional fields
    level = 'INFO'
    verify = True

get_client()
```

Does that work for you?

---

Code is read from top to bottom by the python internpreter; at this point the functions that are defined are registered in the global namespace, but the content of those functions does not get executed yet (just syntax checking is done) unless they are specifically invoked.

For example:

```
def f1():
    print('1')

print('A')
f1()
print('B')

def f2():
    print('2')
```

Here `f1()` is registered and then it is executed even before `f2()` has been registered in the namespace. The output of running the example would be:

```
A
1
B
```

`f2()` never gets called in this code, so its print statement never writes anything to the output.

Comment: Thank you , why does the order doesn’t matter when calling a function from another ?

Comment: because when executing a function, at that point both function names usually have been defined in the namespace

Comment: Is code defined outside function , executed even before functions are defined ?

Comment: @PunterVicky I edited my answer; I hope that answers some of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling on a function before you have defined it.

Try:

```
def get_client():
    # optional fields
    level = 'INFO'
    verify = True

get_client()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python interpreter reads from top to bottom. Thus, you need to call your function AFTER you have defined it:

```
def get_client():
    # optional fields
    level = 'INFO'
    verify = True

get_client()
```